# When is it reasonable to flag a suspected user of a sock puppet?

Tags: discussion

I came across a low-reputation profile today which has several Android/Java answers which are wrong in blatant ways (e.g. the code would never compile, does not even address the question, etc. and some have "This didn't help" type comments too). Despite this each of those recent answers has upvotes and another user with the same location listed also responds to comments on some answers to defend this account.

I noticed the pattern after I downvoted an answer and immediately the score was 'corrected' from zero to one by an upvote

Because the same is true for all of his most recent answers (although not all answers for the account), I suspect one of the accounts is a sock-puppet for the other - but there is no proof (it could just as easily be sympathy votes).

Would it be reasonable to flag an answer for a moderator?

Is it even the job of the community to care about such things or should it be left for automated scripts only?

Comment: I would flag. ----

Comment: You don't have to use the word "sock-puppet" but the description you gave of the activity and flagging for Moderator attention as "suspicious voting activity" would be **absolutely** the right course IMO.

Comment: FWIW, I went through your comments and found the user you're talking about, and checked them out. Looks like a voting ring. You should definitely flag.

Comment: Yeah - flag with the symptoms, not the diagnosis.  The mods will catch on immediate that you suspect puppetry/ringing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone. My intent was not to expose specifically who I meant, but there's no way to 'cover my tracks' on my profile even if I delete any comments

Comment: @NickCardoso well, you provided a timeline (today) and a crime scene (android/java tags). Sherlock Magisch was not really challenged today ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Right, so I took a gander at your profile and found who you're talking about. I also took a look at some of their answers. In this case I agree you should flag. While we can't know for sure if anything fishy is going on, here are some signs you should look out for:

- Do both of these users interact a lot more with each other than with others of the site?
- If you look at their reputation entries, do votes happen in a pattern fashion, and close together, to usually no further activity?

An example of something that looks *kinda* fishy would be this:

[image]

*(anonymized to not start a witch hunt against the guy you accused)*

- Are both users active at the same time?

Generally speaking, you shouldn't comment or take action yourself. Even with these red flags, a moderator is still the only one who can know for sure. So flag it for a moderator with a custom flag text explaining your findings.

Answer (score 16):

Flag one of their answers, explaining your observations. Something like:

> A lot of this user's answers are blatantly incorrect, non-compiling or not answering the question at hand, yet are being upvoted even after being downvoted by others (such as me). Can you look into voting fraud?

Oh, and it doesn't require many clicks to see which user you mean and which user would be suspect of being complicit in the voting fraud.