# What should I do with plagiarised answers to questions asked by a deleted (potential sock-puppet) user when my moderator flags have been declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, plagiarism, voting-fraud, sock-puppets

*Firstly, apologies for the long-windedness of the title - it was hard to come up with a good title that conveyed what I wanted to ask.*

I came across a user who has been a member for three months, asking many questions until one day, something odd (in my opinion) happened:

- In a 44 minute period, they answered 12 questions<sup>*</sup>. The user had posted no other<sup>*</sup> answers in the three months preceding that.
- Every single answer<sup>*</sup> was an answer to a question by the same user.
- Some of the answers plagiarised other answers to the question (with less detail).
- Every answer<sup>*</sup> was accepted in seconds: between 10 and 81 seconds, and with a mean time of 24 seconds.
- The question-asker's account was deleted some time in the two and a half hours after accepting the last answer.

I flagged one of the answers, saying

> I am incredibly suspicious of this user: they have answered 12 questions in a 2 hour period which have all been accepted. All were asked by the (now deleted) (*redacted username*) - from what I can tell, all questions were asked around 1-5am - so the same time zone as this user. This feels like a sock-puppet account

and the flag was marked "Helpful".

I went through some of the answers by the user to spot other issues, trying to help the moderator(s) who'd be dealing the the issue, and spotted two of the answers clearly plagiarise other answers, and one which just rehashes the other answers. Of those flags, one was marked "Helpful" and for the two other flags I got the moderator feedback:

> [image: obfuscated screenshot of the relevant flags. Two flags have "declined - One flag would be enough. Flagging all of these posts adds to the workload of the moderation team", and two flags were marked "helpful"]

Admittedly, as can be seen in the screenshot above, for the three subsequent flags I copy/pasted the message of the first flag and added my plagiarism concerns onto the end of the message so the moderator might have assumed that the flag comments were the same (they were about 75% the same so I can fully understand that).

In a sense whether or not the question-asking account was a sock-puppet of the answering account is immaterial because it's been deleted<sup>+</sup>, but the plagiarism is still definitely present.

I'm reluctant to flag the plagiarised answers again as I don't want to have the flags declined again, but at the same time the plagiarism is still there.

For very obvious reasons I've taken care to keep the identity of the users secret.

What should I do here?

---

<sup>*</sup>As (at least) one of the answers has been deleted and I am not a 10k user I can only get the stats for eleven of the twelve (or more) answers.

<sup>+</sup>In [*What happens if a user has 2 accounts that vote on each others posts?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284754/1364007), [Martijn Pieters♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) [answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284756/1364007):

> Such behaviour is considered voting fraud, and moderators will remove the extra account (called a sockpuppet) if found out. All such votes will be nullified. Generally, the perpetrating account will be put on a temporary account suspension.

Since the second account has been deleted I guess nothing needs to be done.

---

**Related questions**:

- [What happens if a user has 2 accounts that vote on each others posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284754/1364007)
- [When is it reasonable to flag a suspected user of a sock puppet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364597/1364007)
- [How do we deal with plagiarized answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268629/1364007)

Comment: Pretty sure the moderator missed the plagiarism addendum there.

Comment: I wonder why you've copied the sock-puppet stuff into the other flags. These flags are there for being plagiarized answers, not for being from a sock-puppet, because that has been answered. And rehashing other answers isn't forbidden (when the other answers are credited).

Comment: @Tom: in this case the answers where short, completely devoid of detail, and clearly only there for the author of the question to mark as accepted. I can see from Wai's flags that it wasn't the 'rehashing other answers' part that was the real issue here. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters That understandable, so the flag text should really have been clearer about the (new) issue at hand. But your answer covers that already :).

Comment: @Tom it was quite early in the morning and I must not have been thinking 100% clearly. I knew that there were two issues with some of the posts so raised them both in the flags. Just removing the copy/pasta would have been sufficient, I guess - especially since there were 2 1/2 lines of text before the actual reason I was raising the flag.

Comment: Presumably both accounts have been dealt with now?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes - the original (question-asking, possibly sock-puppet) account was deleted before I got to it. As for the main account which answered the questions: all their answers were deleted by the time Martijn Pieters posted his answer, and the account itself was deleted some time after that. I've also edited the question to state that there were no other (undeleted) answers than the 12 in question.

Comment: @WaiHaLee - Thank you for your time and effort helping improve the site by bringing all this to the mods' attention!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

> Admittedly, as can be seen in the screenshot above, for the three subsequent flags I copy/pasted the message of the first flag and added my plagiarism concerns onto the end of the message so the moderator might have assumed that the flag comments were the same (they were about 75% the same so I can fully understand that).

I'm not the moderator that handled those flags but I'm pretty sure that is exactly what happened. Moderators have big piles of flags to process, and we can easily succumb to incorrect pattern matching here.

We *love* diligent members of the community that seek out piles of plagiarism and let us know what source these came from, etc. Do flag issues like these, but don't copy and paste a big block of text. :-)

Perhaps the best way is to just focus on that one post each time, and put the immediate problem up front. Something like:

> Plagiarised from [post link], part of a series of answers posted to questions with a common author and accepted in a short time span. Please delete.

The information you put at the start is interesting too, but we'd only need a single flag with that information, and we can take it from there. I know that if I found flags with *part of a series* or *this is the 3rd flag I've raised for this user*, etc., I'd check for other flagged posts for this user (there is a separate view for that) and investigate further as to what is going on. I do so anyway the moment I find a case of plagiarism.

I have now deleted all those answers (they were all posted within 45 minutes, and had no value whatsoever).

Comment: Thank you for dealing with this so quickly. I think this is the first time I've actually come across any anomalous behaviour like this so, for some reason, decided to copy/paste the text from the initial flag on each instance. This has been a good learning experience for me: thanks.

Comment: At the risk of leaving an inappropriate "thanks" comment, this question and answer are a crystal clear example of the power of smart people doing it right to improve everyone's experience. Thanks.